# How to create adjacency matrix from txt file containing -city1 city2 distance-

Tags: c, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to generate an adjacency matrix from a file containing info on "city1 city2 distance" (snippet below). However, I can't find a way to represent this in an adjacency matrix in C given that the cities get repeated. Any little help appreciated.

```
Bern Brussels 497
Amsterdam Bern 558
Amsterdam Munich 526
Bern Munich 311
Bern Trieste 489
```

Comment: There's several common representations for adjacency matrix. For example, with boost, [`adjacency_matrix`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html), [`adjacency_list`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html).

Comment: You need to first map these city names to integers into an array. Like Bern = 0 and Amsterdam = 1, Munich = 2, Brussels = 3 and Trieste = 4. Now you have a simple graph from with edges that are represented like 0 3 497. To create a mapping you can use string algorithms to compare the string. If you were using c++, it would have been a lot easier cause you could have used a map<string, int>